# Extract value from event path - lambda function

Tags: node.js, regex, string, aws-lambda, extract

The lambda I am working on gets triggered through API gateway.
I want to extract the a specific value from the path in the URL.

Sample URL : `{id}/contacts`

or

`{id-0}/{id}/contacts`

In order to extract the path variable I am using `event.pathParamters`
which gives me the value, but I need to only extract `{id}` from the path.

I am using the following code to split the path param and extract the `{id}`, but this is not a feasible option:

```
arr = path.split("/");
id = arr[arr.length-2];
```

Are there better ways to extract `{id}`? The position of this id will be always last right before api name (in his case `<<contacts>>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would extract the string which is located between the last two occurrences of `/` or the first occurrence if two `/` do not exist

```
([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/tZNhrk/1

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ZygD. I think I can work with this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following;

```
import re
str = '{id-0}/{id}/contacts'            # example
api_name = 'contacts'                   # api name
m = re.search(r'[^/]+(?=/%s)' % api_name, str)
if m:
    id = m.group()
```

The regex `[^/]+(?=/%s)` matches a string of non-slash characters which is followed by a slash and the specified api_name. If the regex matches, `m.group()` is assigned to it.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't know what the api_name would be.